# How to detect encosed area in iOS and fill color inside that?

Tags: ios, drawing

I need to create an app just like Paint application in Windows. Please check out the video at this link

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/56721867/Screen%20Recording.mov

This is how I need my app to be working.
I am able to draw the lines and fill color by using **UIBezierPath** and **CGContext** class but how can I fill the color within the enclosed area by tapping inside that as shown in the video. Please just let me know the approach and which class in iOS can make this possible.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This tool is called Flood Fill:

You can find information about flood fill from following site:
[Flood fill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill)
[Lode's Computer Graphics Tutorial Flood Fill](http://lodev.org/cgtutor/floodfill.html)

If you want an Objective - C example that visit : [UIImageScanlineFloodfill](https://github.com/Chintan-Dave/UIImageScanlineFloodfill)

Answer (score 1):

We have a `UIBezierPath` property `containsPoint:`

Add the following code in `- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`

```
if ([aPath containsPoint:touchloc1]) {
//then set a flag value.
            }
```

And in `- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect` method add the following code

```
if (flag){
   [[UIColor redColor] setFill];
    [yourPath fill];
}
else{
//Whatever code requires for your drawing.
}
```

Hope it work's.

Comment: http://lists.apple.com/archives/quartz-dev/2008/Aug/msg00079.html gone through this, same as UIBezierPath we can set flag if touch is inside your drawing.So you can use pathContainsPoint: forMode: instead of containsPoint: to set the flag.

Answer (score 0):

As CRDAve mentioned This Link Helped me a lot.Please visit https://github.com/Chintan-Dave/UIImageScanlineFloodfill

and use following code in your - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event

```
if (Fill_clicked==1) {

    UIImage *image1 = [paintingView.image floodFillFromPoint:lastPoint withColor:newcolor andTolerance:tolorance];
    paintingView.image=image1;
}
```

lastpoint is from above method.I set tolorance to 10.